# Loop does not return correct values for piecewise function

Tags: matlab, if-statement, for-loop, piecewise

I have tried to write a code, part of a bigger program, that would return value of `z` at every point of `s`. However, when I run the code I only get `z=0`, or if last `else` is ignored code returns zero vector.

Does someone have a clue where I made mistake? I have used method 1 from this [source](http://www.matrixlab-examples.com/piecewise-function.html). Any help will be greatly appreciated, I have trying to get this work for months now.

```
% clc;close all; %// not generally appreciated
%initial values
b=1.25;
h=0.313;

%define the s coordinate
s= 0:0.001:2*(b+h); 

%create zero matrix for speed
z=zeros(size(s));

%calculate z at every point of s coordinate
for i =length(s)
   if 0 <= s(i) && s(i) <=b   %0<=s<=b
       z=0.5*h;

   elseif b <= s(i) && s(i) <=(b+h)   %b<=s<=(b+h)
       z=0.5*h+((-0.5*h)/(b+h-b))*(s-b);

   elseif b <= s(i) && s(i) <=(b+h)    %(h+b)<=s<=(b+h)
       z=-0.5*h;

   elseif b <= s(i) && s(i) <=(b+h)    %(h+2b)<=s<=(2b+2h)
       z=-0.5*h+((-0.5*h)/(b+h-b))*(s-b);
   else z=0;

   end
end
```

For further reference, this solved my problem. Thank you @Dan!

```
 %// initial values
   b=1.25;
   h=0.313;
   %// define the s coordinate
   s= 0:0.001:2*(b+h);
   %// Create z
   z = zeros(size(s));
   idx1 = 0 <= s & s <=b;
   idx2 = b <= s & s <=(b+h);
   idx3 = (b+h) <= s & s <= (2*b+h);
   idx4 = (2*b+h) <= s & s <=(2*b+2*h);
   z(idx1) = 0.5*h;
   z(idx2) = 0.5*h+((-0.5*h-0.5*h)/(b+h-b))*(s(idx2)-b);
   z(idx3) = -0.5*h;
   z(idx4) =-0.5*h+((0.5*h+0.5*h)/((2*b+2*h-b)-(h+b+b)))*(s(idx4)-b)
```

Comment: My guess is that you want to write z(i) on the LHS

Comment: You probably want to read up on the [basics](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/getstart.pdf). Apart from this you only run the code for the last element of s. The correct syntax is `for i=1:length(s)`, or simply use a range based for loop as `for i=s` since you actually want to do something with every element in `s`. Apart from this you need to consider adding index to `z`. In Matlab you will overwrite `z` if you write like this (since you redefine `z` from vector of length N to a scalar). This would give an error in many programming languages but Matlab permits this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many issues with your code. You need to assign to an index of `z` otherwise you're just overwirting a scalar every time (i.e. `z(i)=...`). You need to loop over a vector so `fori=1:length(s)` and your last three loop conditions are identical!

```
%// initial values
b=1.25;
h=0.313;

%// define the s coordinate
s= 0:0.001:2*(b+h); 

%// create zero matrix for speed
z=zeros(size(s));

%// calculate z at every point of s coordinate
for i = 1:length(s)
   if 0 <= s(i) && s(i) <=b                   %// 0<=s<=b
       z=0.5*h;

   elseif b <= s(i) && s(i) <=(b+h)           %// b<=s<=(b+h)
       z(i)=0.5*h+((-0.5*h)/(b+h-b))*(s-b);

   elseif (b+h) <= s(i) && s(i) <= (2*b+h)    %// (h+b)<=s<=(2b+h)
       z(i)=-0.5*h;

   elseif (2*b+h) <= s(i) && s(i) <=(2*b+2*h) %// (h+2b)<=s<=(2b+2h)
       z(i)=-0.5*h+((-0.5*h)/(b+h-b))*(s-b);
   else z(i)=0;

   end
end
```

With all the said, in MATLAB you don't even need a loop at all to do this and it is usually preferable not to use one:

```
%// initial values
b=1.25;
h=0.313;
%// define the s coordinate
s= 0:0.001:2*(b+h);
%// Create z
z = zeros(size(s));
idx1 = 0 <= s && s <=b;
idx2 = b <= s && s <=(b+h);
idx3 = (b+h) <= s && s <= (2*b+h);
idx4 = (2*b+h) <= s && s <=(2*b+2*h);
z(idx1) = 0.5*h;
z(idx2) = 0.5*h+((-0.5*h)/(b+h-b))*(s(idx2)-b);
z(idx3) = -0.5*h;
z(idx4) = -0.5*h+((-0.5*h)/(b+h-b))*(s(idx4)-b);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b=1.25;
h=0.313;

%define the s coordinate
s= 0:0.001:2*(b+h); 

%create zero matrix for speed
z=zeros(size(s));

%calculate z at every point of s coordinate
for ii =1:length(s)
   if 0 <= s(ii) && s(ii) <=b   %0<=s<=b
       z(ii)=0.5*h;

   elseif b <= s(ii) && s(ii) <=(b+h)   %b<=s<=(b+h)
       z(ii)=0.5*h+((-0.5*h)/(b+h-b))*(s(ii)-b);

   elseif b <= s(ii) && s(ii) <=(b+h)    %(h+b)<=s<=(b+h)
       z(ii)=-0.5*h;

   elseif b <= s(ii) && s(ii) <=(b+h)    %(h+2b)<=s<=(2b+2h)
       z(ii)=-0.5*h+((-0.5*h)/(b+h-b))*(s(ii)-b);
   else z(ii)=0;

   end
end
```

Let your `for` loop run over more than 1 iteration, hence the `for ii = 1:length(s)`.

Use allocation per element, thus `z(ii) = some function`

[Don't use `i` as a variable.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab)